# Plot class activation heatmap of Caffe Model in Python

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, python, feature-extraction, representation-learning

Given the following 3 research papers, the authors have shown different heatmap graphical representations for features of the trained CNN models:

1. On the performance of Convnet feature for place recognition: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04158)
   [image: heatmap_1]
2. NetVLAD: CNN architecture for weakly supervised place recognition: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07247)
   [image: heatmap_2]
3. Deep Learning Features at Scale for Visual Place Recognition: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05105)
   [image: heatmap_3]

Does anyone know the easiest heatmap implementation in Python given `deploy.protxt` and `model_wights_bias.caffemodel` files?

PS: I am aware of the following answers and packages: [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020894/how-to-superimpose-heatmap-on-a-base-image), [package1](https://github.com/metalbubble/CAM) but they do not provide these solutions shown in figures above!

Thanks,